# Two objects that need to reference each other. Bad Idea?

Tags: c++, dependencies, friend

I am developing a very small and simple game engine in C++. I have a Creature class and a Weapon class. The Creature needs to know what Weapon(s) it has and each Weapon needs to know the Creature that has it. The main reason why I'd like the Weapon to know what Creature has it is to prevent it from destroying its own Creature (when Weapon attacks, will detect all Creatures it collides with and kill them, except the Creature that has the Weapon).

Here is what the (simplified) Creature class looks like:

```
class Creature {
    private:
    Weapon* weapon_;
    public:
    void SetWeapon(Weapon* w){
        // do some other stuff (e.g. remove Weapon from any other Creatures)
        weapon_ = w;
        w->creature_ = this;
    }
}
```

Here is what the (simplified) Weapon class looks like:

```
class Weapon{
    friend class Creature; // Creature needs access to creature_ pointer
    private:
    creature_;
}
```

As you can see, I have made Creature a friend class of Weapon so that the setWeapon() method of Creature can set the private creature_ pointer appropriately.

My concrete questions:

1. I have heard that two objects referencing each other is bad design. But in my case, how would I go about NOT doing this? I really "feel" that every Creature should know what Weapon it has and every Weapon should know what Creature has it (so that it doesn't damage that Creature). Is there any way of achieving what I want WITHOUT having these two classes reference each other? I have encountered this SAME problem over and over again in my game engine with Map/Entity, Inventory/Item, etc...It seems like whenever I have a "Container" class and an "Item" class, this referencing problem reappears. I want to put the responsibility of ADDING the item in only ONE of the classes yet I want BOTH classes to know about each other (i.e. I want the Creature to know its Weapon and the Weapon to know its Creature). Is there any way of achieving this WITHOUT having both items reference each other?
2. Is this design sometimes necessary? Or is there a general way to always avoid it yet achieve the same type of functionality?
3. If this design is really necessary to achieve this type of functionality, is using a friend class the proper way to handle it?

Thank you so much in advance. I am very interested in learning if there is a way to achieve this type of functionality without having the objects reference each other.

Comment: Have you considered having the creature do attacking instead of the weapon? Then you could have the attack() method that is aware of both weapon and creature since the creature has a weapon and the creature is aware of itself.

Comment: @Knox I did think about that, however I want the attack behavior to lie in the weapon, not in the creature. When a creature is told to attack(), it should simply delegate to weapon_.attack(). This would allow a creature to dynamically swap weapons.

Comment: Then perhaps have the creature's attack() method call weapon's _attack(Entity), that way you can call _attack() for each entity within the range of the weapon (excluding itself).

Comment: That's a good idea for some cases, however, this would make things such as "splash" damage much harder to do. The way attack() currently works is, it plays an animation and checks for collisions with the sprite. Even if I had weapon's attack() method take in an Entity as a parameter, I would still have the same issue of checking to make sure that the owning entity is not destroyed. It seems that this double referencing really is necessary in my case. Thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problems happen from time to time, and being resolved by the following technique:

```
class Creature {
public:
    void SetWeapon(Weapon* w) {
        weapon_ = w;
        weapon_->SetCreature(this);
    }
private:
    Weapon* weapon_;
};

class Weapon {
public:
    void SetCreature(Creature* _creature) {
        m_owner = _creature;
    }
private:
    Creature* m_owner;
};
```

As about your broad question - if you face this kind of problems pretty often in the same project, I propose you to reconsider your design solutions.
For example, your proposition about weapon to know it's creature is counterintuitive and doesn't feel right. So start with that assumption and I'm sure you end up with better design where your weapons won't know anything about their owners (like in real life!).

Comment: Great solution, the problem is though that now I wouldn't be able to change what Creature a Weapon belongs to. I probably should have mentioned that in my question, I will go ahead and update it. Thank you!

Comment: @MeLikeyCode you will if you change `Creature& _owner` to `Creature * _owner`

Comment: This would mean that the Weapon::SetCreature() function would have to be public. This would give clients a chance to call it, which is not what I want. The reason for this is because BEFORE a Weapon is set to a creature, I want to do some other stuff. I don't want clients to be able to call a public function to bypass this. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

1. You have heard correct. It is not a good programming practice to use reference objects in this way but then again using `goto` is also considered a bad approach by some. For Alternative solution see below.
2. This design can be used as sometimes we require `goto` loop as well. BUt not liked approach by many.

Alternative solution:
Based on what you require I can suggest an alternative approach hope this helps. Instead of making reference for each other in the their respective classes, You can create `struct` to accomodate both a player object and weapon object. This way it will be easier to manipulate and make changes as per desire. i.e. a player can have many weapons (you can create an array in this case in the `struct`). Each player will have an instance of weapon assosiated with it.

Comment: Interesting solution. However I also have a Map class. It is very intuitive to add Creatures to the map, however adding a CreatureStruct to the map would feel very awkward for users of my game engine. Nonetheless I'm glad you brought this up, I didn't immediately think of this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is very common to have objects refer back and forth.  A common example is a pointer back to a parent. Your concept is perfectly reasonable.  Just make sure that you have your destructor in place so that the object pointers get cleared out.

In `~Weapon()`, clear the `Creature`'s pointer to the weapon, and vice versa.

Comment: Ah, thank you for this answer. The fact that it is common and reasonable makes me feel a lot better about it. Thanks!